# Routing Function in AngularJS Does Not Get Executed

Tags: angularjs

Newbie with AngularJS here.

I have an index.html file below, which references an Javascript file named app.js. The index.html file is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.22" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.2.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controller1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Github Viewers</h1>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In my app.js file, I have the following codes:

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

  app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when("/main", {
        templateUrl: "main.html",
        controller: "controller1"
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo: "/main"});
  });
}());
```

I've set breakpoints (in Chrome Dev Tools) on the line:

```
templateUrl: "main.html",
```

But I am unable to get into this line.

Console Window shows no errors, so I am a little stumped.

Appreciate any insight on where to look further on this.

Comment: A breakpoint there will not work. Change `ng-app="myApp"` to `ng-app="githubViewer"`.

Comment: Even a breakpoint inside an object is not possible. Are you sure angular is bootstrapped (try to put a {{2+2}} in your template)? Where is the code of your "controller1" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong app name.

Change `<html ng-app="myApp">` to `<html ng-app="githubViewer">`

### Edit

You cannot put a breakpoint in that line (`templateUrl: "main.html"`). Note that's an **Object** definition and not a function:

```
{
  templateUrl: "main.html",
  controller: "controller1"
}
```

And like all **Objects**, they are defined in an atomic operation. It's like if all its properties were created at once, meaning that you cannot "break" the execution for a specific property.

I've tested with *Chrome dev tools* and it doesn't even allow me to set a breakpoint in that line. Not sure how you did it...

If you want to check if the `"main.html"` template is being loaded, watch the network tab of the *Chrome dev tools*.

Comment: I did changed the ng-app value to reflect myApp across everything in my app but still, the breakpoint is not being hit.

Comment: @Batuta, updated my answer to explain why you cannot use a breakpoint there. What exactly do you want to check with that breakpoint? Is the app not working? Can you provide a plunker?

Comment: I was able to find out the issue after reading your explanation a couple of times. Turns out in controller1, I have defined app as app=angular.module("myApp", []). Removing the square brackets resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: I've set this as answer as because bmleite posted an elaborate explanation that lead me to discovering what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

I think your dependency injection is missing controller1 module..
if you managing controllers in different module you have to inject it in your app.js

```
 //controller1.js
    angular.module('controllers',[])
     .controller('controller1',function(....)

    //app.js
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["controllers","ngRoute"]);
     ...

//index.html
    ...
     <script src="controller1.js"></script>  
     <script src="app.js"></script> 
    ...
```